# Как отдать в шаблон найденые в базе данных обьекты?

Tags: python, orm, flask

Есть функция вот такого вида
(ORMка PonyORM)

```
@db_session
def select_allvalid_users():
    users = select(x for x in User)
    print(type(users))
    print(users)
    return users
```

возвращает она

```
<class 'pony.orm.core.QueryResult'>
[User[1], User[2]]
```

когда я пытаюсь вернуть отправить это в шаблон

```
usr = select_allvalid_users()
return jsonify(user = usr)
```

он мне говорит

> TypeError: User[1] is not JSON serializable

Как вернуть объект нормально в шаблон, чтоб можно было использовать в шаблоне поля объекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `to_json` из модуля `pony.orm.serialization`.

См. [Serialization to a dictionary and to JSON](http://doc.ponyorm.com/working_with_entity_instances.html#serialization-to-a-dictionary-and-to-json).